# PHP oracle connection not rolling back

Tags: php, database, oracle, commit, rollback

I guess I'm confused about how PHP passes objects or how oracle works.  There are 3 parts to my code:

1. A file that creates a database connection as a global variable
2. Classes that send queries and parameters to the 3rd part.  All of these require_once() the first file, so they should all be using the same connection.
3. An abstract class that binds the parameters and executes the queries. When the classes from (2) are constructed they pass the db connection from the require_once() to this abstract class to use.

The abstract class also has functions for commit and rollback.  I would expect that when I rollback one class from (2), all of those classes are rolled back because they're all using the same global db connection.  But they don't.

What am I not understanding?

The db connection file:

```
<?php
$db = ocilogon(...);
```

The abstract db class

```
abstract class Database {
    private $conn;

    function __construct($conn) {
        $this->conn = $conn;
    }

    protected function query($query, array $params = []) {
        $stid = oci_parse($this->conn, $query);

        foreach($vars as $var => &$val) {
            oci_bind_by_name($stid, $var, $val);
        }

        $success = oci_execute($stid, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT);

        return $success ? $stid : false;
    }

    public function commit() {
        return oci_commit($this->conn);
    }

    public function rollback() {
        return oci_rollback($this->conn);
    }
}
```

A database class

```
require_once(connection_file.php);
require_once(Database.php);

class User extends Database {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct($GLOBALS['db']);
    }

    public function get($id) {
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM users where id = :id';

        $stid = $this->query($query, [':id' => $id]);

        return oci_fetch_assoc($stid);
    }
}
```

An example script

```
require_once(db_user.php);
require_once(db_payment.php);

$user = new User();
$payment = new Payment(); //Another class like User

$user->insert(...);
$payment->insert(...);

//Oops

$user->rollback();

exit;
```

Wouldn't payment also be rolled back?

Comment: No, once a transaction has been committed it stays committed. _If thats what you mean._

Comment: Just because a file is `require_once`'d does not means that all scripts are using the same connection. The connection is specific to each script that loaded the connection script using `require_once` So basically if you have 100 scripts runnning they are all using their own connections and know nothing of the other scripts connections

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I didn't commit.  Also, the abstract class that runs oci_execute passes the parameter OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT.

Comment: Not Oracle expert, but I would assume `OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT` is like doing a `start_transactions()` so all your code would be in transaction mode. But you had better check that.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Let's say that there's 4 files: connection.php, db_user.php, db_payment.php, and add_user.php.  db_user.php and db_payment.php both require_once(connection.php).  Then, add_user.php require_once() db_user.php and db_payment.php. You're saying that inside add_user.php, the db files each have their own connection?

Comment: I think the answer to that conundrum is `require_ONCE` will only include a file ONCE

Comment: Right, so I don't understand how there would be two connections if there's only one global connection.

Comment: I think we are no getting into the territory where I would actually need to see some sample code [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate exactly what you mean.